# Fill up a container with rows of boxes (depending on scrollbar)

Tags: html, css

How can I fill up a 500px wide container, with `overflow-y` set to `scroll`,  with rows of (e.g.) 2 boxes in a way which works for all browsers?

[image: What I want To Achieve]

The problem is that different browsers have different scrollbar widths and that the scrolbbar might, or might not take up space in the container. Thats why I can't just give the boxes a width of 250px.

How should I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you give the boxes a width of 50%?

Comment: No, because the scrollbar might take up some of the space of the container. Currently I'm trying to wrap each row in a div and then giving each box a width of 50%, but still no luck..

Comment: Hmm looks like the padding of the boxes screws up the calculated width when I set it to 50%. Almost there....

Comment: Add the CSS ``box-sizing: border-box`` this should reign the box and scrollbar in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out the padding on the individual boxes was screwing up the calculated width of the boxes (which had width set to 50%). Removing the padding on the box and creating an inner-box with margin to simulate the padding, solved my problem.

Furthermore:

As user deiga comments above: using `box-sizing: border-box`will also solve the problem